# How to print without showing the Printing Dialogue?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, printing

I have this demo app, I need to print FlowDocument without pop-up the Printing Dialogue from the operational system. Do you have any idea how to do it? Or you know other possible posolution?

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
    pd.ShowDialog();
    if (pd.ShowDialog() != true) return;

    flowDocument.PageHeight = pd.PrintableAreaHeight;
    flowDocument.PageWidth = pd.PrintableAreaWidth;

    IDocumentPaginatorSource idocument = flowDocument as IDocumentPaginatorSource;

    pd.PrintDocument(idocument.DocumentPaginator, "Printing Flow Document...");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

delete this lines:

```
pd.ShowDialog();
if (pd.ShowDialog() != true) return;
```

Comment: thanks but .....removing that line of code does not help, the print dialogue still appears

Comment: Also delete the one before that: `pd.ShowDialog();`